# Event Listener **STILL** not listening?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

.addEventListener doesn't appear to be picking up on my clicks, and after hours of going over this, I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong. I've made the suggested changes, but still getting no response from clicks?
Here's a list of the errors I'm seeing as well

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGmDF.jpg)

document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);

**main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .nav-link{
      cursor:pointer;
    }
  </style>
  
  </head>
  <body>
  
  
<div class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link active" id="home-link">Home</div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link" id="search-link">Search</div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link" id="add-member-link">Add Member</div>
  </li>
</ul>

 
  <div id="app">
  </div>
  <!--GET CONTENT HERE-->
</div>

<!--Optional JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>

  function loadSearchView(){
        loadView("search");
    }    
  function loadView(options){
   
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
    }).loadView(options);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);


  </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**search.html**

```
<h1>This is a test</h1>
```

**loadPartials**

```
function loadPartialHTML_(partial){
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent();
}

function loadSearchView(){

  return loadPartialHTML_("search");

}

function loadAddMembersView(){

  return loadPartialHTML_("addmember");

}

function loadView(view){

if(view == "search"){
  return loadPartialHTML_("search")
}else if (view == "addmembers"){
  return loadPartialHTML_("addmembers");
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The D in `getElementById` isn't capitalized

Comment: That's the way the apps script auto-finishes it. I've tried it both ways with no change

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

1. Change your `loadview` function to handle an object that accepts the function you wanna load, callback functions, and params. You will need it in the future if you are intending to scale your system.

```js
function loadView(options) {
    var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
    var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function () { } : options.callback;

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (html) {
       document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
       typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
    })[options.func]();
}
```

2. After that make sure you call `getElementById()` correctly with no capitalized ID at the end. The call should be like this:

```js
document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);
```

3. `loadSearchView` function should look like this in your case

```js
function loadSearchView() {
   loadView({ func: "loadSearchView" });
}
```

4. But remember that if you want to do something after `loadSearchView` you can call it on the callback function, and also send parameters too. Somethings like this:

```js
function loadSearchView() {
   loadView({ func: "loadSearchView", callback: afterSearchViewLoads params: { id: e.target.dataset.id }});
}
```

When `afterSearchViewLoads` is another function to be declared and deal with the search.html after it loads with the `eventListenter`. And params usually is called from a clickEventHandler(e) function that deals with elements ins you interface.

An example is to create another function called

```js
document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("click", clickEventHandler);

//and

function clickEventHandler(e){
 if(e.target.matches(".some-button-class)){
    doSomething(e);
}
```

Your problem in my opinion was only the call to `getElementById`. The rest is only suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

It should be `getElementById` and not `getElementByID`. One reason why `getElementById` is not working when you tried it is Apps Script can't recognize the function you want to run in your eventListener (`[options.func]()`).

You could test if your eventListener is working by adding `alert()` in your `loadSearchView()`.

### Example:

**Code:**

```
function loadSearchView(){
   alert("Im in loadSearchView")
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Alternative for `addEventListener()`  is to use `onClick()` directly to the `nav-item`.

**From:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link" id="search-link">Search</div>
</li>
```

**To:**

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <div class="nav-link" id="search-link" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadSearchView()">Search</div>
</li>
```

---

Since Apps Script cannot recognize `[options.func]()` and you want it to become dynamic, you can pass the `options` to  the server side and use that to identify which html to display.

### Example:

**Code:**

*main.html*

```
<script>
   function loadSearchView(){
      loadView("search");
   }
   
   function loadView(options){
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
     document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
    }).loadView(options);
   }

   document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);
</script>
```

*Code.gs*

```
function loadView(view){
  if(view == "search"){
    return loadPartialHTML_("search")
  }else if(view == "addmembers"){
    return loadPartialHTML_("addmembers");
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [onClick()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_onclick.asp)
- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)